# How to insert a timer in popen function C++?

Tags: c++, timer, timeout

I have this function, the input is the var "cmd" for example a dmesg command.

```
int i = 0;
char * bufferf;
bufferf = ( char * ) calloc( sizeof ( char ) , 200000 );
char buffer[1000][1280];
memset(buffer,0,1000 * 1280);
memset(bufferf,0,strlen(bufferf));
FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");

if (!pipe){
    send(client_fd,"EXCEPTION",9,0);
}

while(!feof(pipe)) {
    if(fgets(buffer[i], 128, pipe) != NULL)
    {
        strcat(bufferf, buffer [i] );
    }
    i++;
}
pclose(pipe);
std::cout << bufferf ;
send(client_fd,bufferf,strlen(bufferf),0); }
```

Well. My goal is to calculate the amount of time between the start and the end of the while statement, by adding for each time a var that count the time passed.

For example dmesg is ~700 lines of output. The while runs for 700 times I have to add 700 times the amount of time to calculate the total sum.
How can I do that?
I've tried with difftime but it doesn't work very well.
Any other solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no need to `memset(bufferf,0,...)` since `bufferf` is already zeroed due to `calloc(3)`. (And allocating a megabyte on the stack may be asking for trouble -- the `[ stack ]` space on all my processes on my system is typically 132K, with one process using 352K of stack. Be careful.)

Comment: Thanks! But I need that dimension to allocate output very big like dmesg and much more.
If you have a better solution for that, tell me.

Comment: You can `malloc(3)` your huge buffer :)

Comment: One more trick, please. Can I use that calloc with a free function that deallocates the memory?

Comment: `calloc(3)` in fact requires you to use `free(3)` to free the memory when you are done -- or you leak the memory that was allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an extremely basic class that uses [clock()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/) to measure the time:

```
#include <ctime>

class Timer
{
   private:
      clock_t _start, _duration;
   public:
      Timer() : _start(0), _duration(0) { }

      void start() { _start = clock(); }
      void stop() { _duration = clock() - _start; }     
      float getTime() { return (float)_duration / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; }
};
```

Obviously multiply by 1000 if you want to display the time in milliseconds.

And then just:

```
Timer t;
t.start();
// do something
t.stop();

cout << "Duration: " << t.getTime() << endl;
```

Also, take note of what sarnold said, `buffer` is huge.

Comment: Ok but CLOCKS_PER_SEC "could not be resolved".
I've done the import of the library.
What's wrong?
Thank you

Comment: @user840718 really? `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` should be defined in `<ctime>` (ie. `<time.h>`). You did include that didn't you?

Comment: um, it's obsolete but I guess you could try `CLK_TCK`. If it's not too long perhaps you could provide all your code, there might be a small error.

Comment: Yeah I saw that before, try `<time.h>` instead of `<ctime>`.

Comment: Build without errors, but my output of dmesg is set to 0.
I'll try tomorrow.
Thank you.